# return string in devextreme pivot grid based on neighbouring cell value

Tags: jquery, devexpress

```js
$("#sales").dxPivotGrid({

  allowSorting: true,
  showColumnTotals: false,
  showColumnGrandTotals: false,
  showRowGrandTotals: false,
  showRowTotals: false,
  allowFiltering: true,

  height: 440,
  showBorders: true,
  fieldChooser: {
    enabled: false
  },
  "export": {
    enabled: true,
    fileName: "Sales"
  },
  dataSource: {
    fields: [{
      caption: "subject",
      width: 120,
      dataField: "subject",
      area: "row"
    }, {
      caption: "studentname",
      dataField: "studentname",
      width: 150,
      area: "column",

    }, {
      caption: "PassingMarks",
      dataField: "PassingMarks",
      dataType: "number",
      summaryType: "sum",
      area: "data"
    }, {
      caption: "ActualMarks",
      dataField: "ActualMarks",
      dataType: "number",
      summaryType: "sum",
      area: "data"
    }, {
      caption: "Comments",

      area: "data",
      calculateSummaryValue: function(e) {
        

        if (e.value("PassingMarks") < e.value("ActualMarks")) {
          return "Pass";
        } else {
          return "fail";
        }


      }
    }],
    store: sales
  }
});
```

I am using devextreme pivot grid displaying marks of student name wise(column). I to want return string cell value in column "comments" using `calculateSummaryValue()` based on neighbouring cell  PassingMarks,ActualMarks. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
caption: "Comments", isMeasure: true, calculateSummaryValue: function (e) {
        if (e.value("PassingMarks") < e.value("ActualMarks")) {
          return "Pass";
        } else {
          return "fail";
        }                
}
```